# 64-bit python 2.5/2.6+windows 7 "import socket" DLL load error

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I installed latest 64-bit Python 2.5. I run the shell, and try to `import socket`, and get:

```
>>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python25\lib\socket.py", line 45, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 193
```

I try the same with 64-bit Python 2.6.6, and get:

```
>>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26-64\lib\socket.py", line 46, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

what's the deal? (I double-checked, yes, the OS is 64-bit).

UPDATE: I also have 32-bit python installed on this machine.. if this is a conflict, how can I install both versions of python and have them behave nicely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two errors are the same error, code 193, reported two different ways. It is caused because your 64 bit Python is trying to load a 32 bit DLL.

It's hard to say exactly why this has happened. Perhaps you installed some 32 bit Python modules by mistake. Perhaps there is some confusion in paths.

However, often the easiest way to get around this sort of problem is to switch to 32 bit Python which runs impeccably on 64 bit Windows.  A side benefit is that you will sometimes want to use modules that are only available in 32 bit form – 64 bit module support is still a little patchy.

Comment: i do have 32-bit python installed.. the issue is that i'm using virtualboxapi, which uses COM, which requires python to have the same bitness as virtualbox, which is 64-bit =(. otherwise i'd be all for 32-bit only.

Comment: Hmm. Clearly the import of _socket results in an attempt to load a 32 bit DLL. It would be nice if the error message told you which one: %1 isn't much use. If I were you I would not try stripping my PATH environment variable to barebones. It might be something on your PATH that is causing the problems. Do this at the command line, then launch Python so that your keep the experiment local to that console window!

Comment: oh the issue was me being retarded, i.e. the directory i was running the script from had a left-over py2exe thing which i guess had 32-bit dlls in it. thanks for the help thou!

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me when I used py2exe to build a (32-bit) binary and then ran the 64 bit interpreter in the same directory. Apparently (and reasonably) it will pick the local instance of the socket module (which then loads a 32-bit dll) over the interpreter's socket module (which correctly loads a 64-bit dll).